# How can I overload the unary negative (minus) operator in Python?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

```
class Card():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

c = Card(1)
d = -c
```

I expect `d` to be a `Card` object and `d.val` to be -1. How I can do that?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It sounds like you want the unary minus operator on `Card` to return a new card with the value negated. If that's what you want, you can define the `__neg__` operator on your class like this:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __neg__(self):
        return Card(-self.val)
```

`__neg__` is included in the list of methods that can be overridden to customise arithmetic operations in the docs: [emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Comment: How can I know all the predefined functions, such as __neg__?

Comment: pretty helpful :)

Comment: This is described in the Python docs for emulating numeric types. The operation you asked about is "unary minus". Unary meaning it acts on one operand.) https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Comment: @maxyue refer to this [page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) of Python documentation for Python operators.