# question about method overriding special negation method in python and how to return it properly

Tags: python, methods, operator-overloading

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45454777/13786695
I was wondering if anyone could explain the answer to the above post. I was wondering why you would need to return Card(-self.val) instead of (-self.val) without calling the class Card. Isn't 'self' already 'tied' with the object you are using the unary function on? so why would you need to reiterate that the Card class be called on (-self.val).

I would expect that if you printed d you would get -1 just by returning (-self.val) without calling the Card class.

Comment: "I would expect that if you printed d you would get -1 just by returning (-self.val) without calling the Card class." - but they don't *want* -1. They want a Card.

Comment: @user2357112 ohh okay I understand now, I just thought that since they had originally called the card class on the object and assigned it to the variable C, I didn't think they would have had to reiterate that class when editing the attribute of that object.